# CSP (Content-Security-Policy) not recognizing url origin

Tags: php, google-chrome, iis, content-security-policy

I am trying to get nicEditor to work on my site, however I am having trouble with the CSP(Content-Security-Protocols).
I downloaded nicEditor locally and have no problems initializing it.

However when trying to upload images it gives me this error:

> Refused to connect to 'https://api.imgur(.)com/3/image' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src
>   'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so
>   'default-src' is used as a fallback.

This is the metadata tag I am currently using. I only added https://api.imgur(.)com/3/image to default-src for debuging.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https://api.imgur.com 'self' 'unsafe-eval' ; connect-src https://api.imgur.com;  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

From my understanding this should whitelist content and connections to imgur api but that is not happening. any ideas?

Comment: Specifying a CSP in form of a meta tag is not recommended, since it limits the effectivity of the protection. It should be specified as protocol header.

Comment: Using the meta tag is fine for some cases, e.g. static pages. @dan `https://api.imgur(.)com/3/image` doesn't appear to be a valid URL and the error message does not align with the policy you provided. The policy you provided specifies a connect-src but the error message says that it does not. Something doesn't add up.